# Wait for mongoose exec to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an issue with a performing a query with moongose and NodeJS

I am trying to perform a search with moongose and depends on the result assign it to a variable but when i print the variable it shows as empty

```
  let queryDict;

  query.exec(function (err, item) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    if (item === null || item.length === 0) {
        queryDict = { 
            status: 'empty',
            comment: 'some comment' 
        };
    }
    else { queryDict = item }
});

console.log(`queryDict: ${queryDict}`);
```

The expected behavior is to have some content in the variable. please help me to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose operations are [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous), so `queryDict` will be `undefined` when your `console.log` statement executes.

You will need to move your `console.log` into the body of the callback you've provided to be able to access the value from your query.

Don't worry if that seems a bit confusing, the asynchronous nature of JavaScript is easy to trip up on if you are new to the paradigm. I'd recommend reading the article linked above and playing around with the examples in the mongoose docs.

Alternately, you could rewrite this using [`async/await`](https://javascript.info/async-await) like so:

```
async function executeQuery () {
    try {
    const item = await query.exec()

    if (item === null || item.length === 0) {
        queryDict = { 
            status: 'empty',
            comment: 'some comment' 
        };

        console.log(`queryDict: ${queryDict}`);
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        handleError(err);
    }
}


executeQuery()
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick, but I really need the console.log outside the async function, there is a way to do this?

Comment: There is now way to do this because mongoose is asynchronous. You'll need to use a callback or a promise to get that value. It sounds like there may be another problem here that might be a good fit for another SO question.